# How to pass form input value into variable in socket.emit parms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, socket.io

I want to pass the `username` input from the form into `socket.emit` `params`. However when I step into `socket.on function`, `userName` is undefined. It should be the scope issue, while I don't know how to fix that.
I omitted some of the codes to simplify the problem. It's not necessary to make the code runable, I just want to get the method how to deal with this problem.

```js
$("button").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setUserName($("input[name=name]").val());
});

var userName;

function setUserName(userName2) {
   userName=userName2;
}

var socket = io();

socket.on('connect', function () {
  var params = {
      name:userName
  }

  socket.emit('join', params, function (err) {
    
  });
});
```

```html
<body class="centered-form">
  <div class="centered-form__form">
    <form>
      <div class="form-field">
        <label>Display name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" autofocus/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-field">
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="/libs/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/chat.js"></script>
```

Comment: `console.log(this)` and take a gander at what it is.  Also you have userName set as a var at the global scope, as far as I can tell from your snippet, so I'm not sure why you are trying to use `this` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You have a scoping issue with userName

```js
$("button").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setUserName($("input[name=name]").val());
});

var userName;

function setUserName(userName) {
  //this refers to the scope of the function
   this.userName=userName;
}

var socket = io();

socket.on('connect', function () {
  var params = {
      //this refers to the scope of the socket
      name:this.userName
  }

  socket.emit('join', params, function (err) {
    
  });
});
```

Try

```js
$("button").click(function (event) {
    console.log('__BUTTON_EVENT__');
    event.preventDefault();
    
    let name = $("input[name=name]").val();
    console.log('__USER_NAME__: ', name);
    setUserName(name);
});

var userName;

function setUserName(name) {
   userName = name;
}

var socket = io();

socket.on('connect', function () {
  var params = {
      name:userName
  }
  console.log('__CONNECTING__: ', params.name);

  socket.emit('join', params, function (err) {
    
  });
});
```

Comment: yes I tried that, however it is still undefined. If I assign an value to userName like var userName="888", the userName in params will be "888".

Comment: More than likely the issue is occuring in the click event or the connection event then. Try console logging when click is called and when on is called. Will post revisions

Comment: Alos, when is the socket connection being initiated?